# How can I write a SQL select query where condition depends upon another table?

Tags: sql, select

I have two tables

1. Loan
2. Repayment Schedule

   ```
   loan: id is primary key

   id, closedon_date
   -
   1,  2022-05-01
   2,  2022-06-01
   ```

   ```
   repayment_schedule: loan_id is Foreign key

   id, loan_id, principal_amount, due_date
   -
   1,  1,        100              2022-05-01  
   2,  1,        100              2022-06-01
   3,  2,        200              2022-05-01  
   4,  2,        200              2022-06-01
   5,  2,        200              2022-07-01
   ```

   I want to write a select SQL query that returns the sum of the principal amount of each loan_id with the condition that the due date is less or equal to the closed-on date.
   Output:

   ```
   loan_id, sum(principal_amount)
   -
   1,        100
   2,        400
   ```

This is the closet approximation to the query

```
select loan_id, sum(principal_amount) from repayment_schedule
where
  repayment_schedule.due_date <= loan.closedon_date
group by loan_id
```

Comment: What to do if the date is NULL, what to do if a id occurs only in one of the two tables?

Comment: Is this question not appropriate for StackOverflow? If so why and how can I ask better questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there

```
select loan_id, sum(principal_amount) from repayment_schedule
JOIN loan ON loan.id = repayment_schedule.loan_id
where
  repayment_schedule.due_date <= loan.closedon_date
group by loan_id
```

Just JOIN with table loan

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT loan_id, sum(principal_amount) 
FROM repayment_schedule s
INNER JOIN loan L
    ON s.[loan_id] = L.[id]
WHERE s.due_date <= l.closedon_date
GROUP BY loan_id
```

[image]